# Android: Customize list view, Table view in adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view, android-adapter

I created a table view in list view adapter programmatically. For that first i created a Adapter layout as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:id="@+id/tablelayout" >
</ableLayout>
```

Then what I have done in the adapter is:

```
public class DemoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    //Global Variable declaration
    Context myContext;
    String[] key, value, loop;

    public DemoAdapter(Context context, String[] key, String[] value, String[] loop){
        super(context, R.layout.demo_screen_adapter, loop);
        this.myContext = context;
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.loop = loop;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null){
            // get reference to the activity
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) myContext).getLayoutInflater();
            // Inflate the custom text which will replace the default text view
            //list_item is a simple linear layout which contain textView1 in it. 
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.demo_screen_adapter, parent, false);
        }

        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(myContext);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView tvKey = new TextView(myContext);
            tvKey.setText(key[(position*5)+i]);
            tvKey.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tvKey.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tableRow.addView(tvKey);

            TextView tvValue = new TextView(myContext);
            tvValue.setText(value[(position*5)+i]);
            tvValue.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tvValue.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tableRow.addView(tvValue);
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

This is working good. In my each list item there is a table view contains around two column and five rows.

Now the **issue** is:

I want to fetch the perticular values on click of list item. I am not able to do so.
What i tried  as:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+(String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But it shows the position on which i click.

What should i do for that please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

In your Custom Adapter.Used a holder.

This is my Custom Adapter

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.samplelogin.CustomerDetails;
import com.samplelogin.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class UserCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Customers> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<Customers> data = new ArrayList<Customers>();

    public UserCustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            ArrayList<Customers> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        UserHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new UserHolder();
            holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.textAddress = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.textLocation = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            holder.btnEdit = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button1);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        Customers user = data.get(position);        
        holder.textName.setText(user.getName());
        holder.textAddress.setText(user.getAddress());
        holder.textLocation.setText("");

        holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Customers user = data.get(position);
                user.setTID(user.getID());
                user.setTName(user.getName());
                user.setTAddress(user.getAddress());
                user.setTTelNo(user.getTelNo());
                user.setTMobileNo(user.getMobileNo());
                user.setTFaxNo(user.getFaxNo());

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, CustomerDetails.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return row;

    }

    static class UserHolder {
        TextView textName;
        TextView textAddress;
        TextView textLocation;
        Button btnEdit;
        Button btnDelete;
    }

}
```

And in my activity. I put data on it by:

declare you variable

```
 // Customer
   ListView CustomerList;
    UserCustomAdapter CustomerAdapter;
    ArrayList<Customers> CustomerArray = new ArrayList<Customers>();
    Button addCustomer;
```

Put fill up your value with a data.

```
        // Customer Tab
cdb = new CustomerDB(getApplicationContext());
int custcount = cdb.getCustomerCount();
if (custcount > 0) {
    List<Customers> cdbL = cdb.getAllCustomers();
    int listSize = cdbL.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {

        CustomerArray.add(new Customers(cdbL.get(i).getDBName()
                .toString(), cdbL.get(i).getDBAddress().toString(),
                cdbL.get(i).getDBTelNo().toString(), cdbL.get(i)
                        .getDBMobileNo().toString(), cdbL.get(i)
                        .getDBFaxNo().toString(), cdbL.get(i).getDBID()
                        .toString()));
    }
}
```

Now, from your list. transfer you data to your custom adapter

```
// set item into adapter
CustomerAdapter = new UserCustomAdapter(MainMaintenance.this,
        R.layout.maintenancetab, CustomerArray);
CustomerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCustomer);
CustomerList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
CustomerList.setAdapter(CustomerAdapter);
```

Here, you can click the item and do what you want. in this sample, i pass my data in a list in a public class and then i go to the next activity.

```
    // get on item click listener
CustomerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Customers user = CustomerArray.get(arg2);
        user.setTID(user.getID());
        user.setTName(user.getName());
        user.setTAddress(user.getAddress());
        user.setTTelNo(user.getTelNo());
        user.setTMobileNo(user.getMobileNo());
        user.setTFaxNo(user.getFaxNo());

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainMaintenance.this,
                CustomerDetails.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

The setOnClickListener in your custom adapter is if you will put a button in you custom adapter :) if youll be confuse just tell me :)

I hope that this sample code will give you an idea and help you.