# How to show data from firebase database in TableLayout android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I searched and didn't find any method to show data that retrieved from firebase databse in a tablelayout.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked. Also have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

To show the data on the table layout you can create:

- An adapter, which is the same way as putting data on the recyclerview or the listview. ref: [Android: Customize list view, Table view in adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626825/android-customize-list-view-table-view-in-adapter)
- Manual putting `tablerow` on the table layout